# Q: Need help to disseminate a crisis in a network

Tags: netlogo

I have created a network of agents where each agent has a GDP value and a GDP growth rate. The agents are interconnected with undirected links.

I have made a countdown that every 200 ticks randomly assign a 'shock status' to 10 agents. When an agent is under shock it gets the value 'in-crisis? = true' and consequentially its GDP growth rate changes.

However, I want to add a second trigger. I want agents with the 'in-crisis? = false' to check their link-neighbors and see if any of them have 'in-crisis? = true'. If they are linked to an agent whose in-crisis is true, then they should check if their own GDP is smaller than half of the GDP of the linked state that has 'in-crisis? = true'. If it is smaller, then the agent will set his own 'in-crisis?' as true.

```
to shock 
  if ticks mod 200 = 0 [ ;; This is the countdown 
  spread-crisis
  ask n-of 10 turtles [  
  become-in-crisis]
  ]
end

to spread-crisis  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; This is the second trigger. I need help here!
  ask turtles with [in-crisis? = false]
    [ if any? link-neighbors with [in-crisis? = true] [
        if any? link-neighbors with [gdp > my-gdp] [
         become-in-crisis ] ]]
end

to-report my-gdp
 report (gdp * 2) 
end

to become-in-crisis
  set in-crisis? true
  let random-years-of-shock 20 + random 100
  set shock-tick random-years-of-shock
end
```

If you have time, please help me to adjust the spread-crisis procedure!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `my-gdp` to `[my-gdp] of myself`.

```
to spread-crisis 
  ask turtles with [not in-crisis?]  [
    if any? link-neighbors with [in-crisis? and gdp > [my-gdp] of myself] [
      become-in-crisis
    ] 
  ]
end
```

Comment: It is very weird, but the code seems not to be working. I did the changes as you suggested, I even tried to simplify by writing '[gdp] of myself', but it does not work. If I solve the problem I will post a comment here. If you have any other input I will greatly appreciate!

I did some test and the code you gave me is correct. There must be some conflict somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. The error was in the first block of code. The spread-crisis procedure was just triggered during one single tick after the countdown. I moved the 'spread-crisis' procedure outside the 'if ticks mod 200 = 0 []' procedure and now it works perfectly. Thank you for the help and for the neat code!